# Galaxy SIII ignoring setDefaultZoom? UPDATE: JellyBean issue with WebView?

Tags: android, webview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

**UPDATE:** This is actually a JellyBean issue:

Emulator running ICS:
[image: ICS Version of WebView]

Emulator running JB:
[image: JB Version of WebView]

So the emulator settings are the same (API level different obviously). Tested and verified on 3 differerent devices: Nexus S, Galaxy Nexus, and GS3.

I have a webView acivity that display's a couple of different web pages. I change the Default Zoom Settings based on what url is being displayed. 
The following line :

`webSettings.setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);`

was producing the view seen in ICS ( I get same behavior with anything 2.2- 4.0.4), but with JellyBean it seems like the DefaultZoom is not being recognized.

Any one else encounter this ?  I feel like this is a bug with JellyBean, but wanted to check back here before submitting.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of a old thread, but if you are still having the same issue I found a setting that fixed a similar issue for me. The issue occurred on Jelly Bean (4.1.2) on a Samsung Tablet.

```
webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me if it works... it should handle the page fitting on the fone screen!

```
 WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't work.  It actually made it look like the picture of the s3 above on my emulator.

Comment: try this WebView.setInitialScale(1);

Comment: if the above dont work.... then try this...

very cheap method to do... but it will work...

mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
mWebView.loadData("your url");
mWebView.reload();
mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: neither idea worked. Still zoomed in too far. That's why I've had the following in :
webSettings.setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
but the s3 seems to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

I "fixed" it on my own app by using getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true).

However that is a misbehavior - and looks wrong on all the other devices.
** Shame to Samsung for breaking the behavior of the API **
Devices working correctly: Galaxy Nexus, HTC One X, etc..

Comment: How did you "fix" it?  You are using setUseWideViewPort on all devices? It doesn't look right in my emulator unless I setDefaultZoom to FAR