# image scaling issue on android jelly bean

Tags: java, android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

When loading an image on webview, it is scaled properly on all devices and OS until ICS. However, after Jelly Bean update, it is not scaled anymore! I found some posts talking about this bug but not able to find the solution yet.

[Galaxy SIII ignoring setDefaultZoom? UPDATE: JellyBean issue with WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288344/galaxy-siii-ignoring-setdefaultzoom-update-jellybean-issue-with-webview)

I will be glad to post some code but I don't know how to attach the problem or which useful code can help. Please suggest. Thank you